# How can I make smart contract non-upgradeable

Tags: smartcontracts, nearprotocol, near

Is there a way to make a smart contract NON-upgradeable on Near?

By default I can always overwrite a contract at an account address. This is different from Ethereum where after deployment the contract gets a new address after which it is by default non-upgradeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contract can be locked by removing the full-access key:

https://docs.near.org/develop/deploy#locking-a-contract

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).